# Difference between values in non-consecutive rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the below data set. There is a value for each day, which is always more than the value of the previous day.

TimeStamps are given in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

```
TimeStamp            Device   Value
-------------------  ------  ---------
25/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150292432
26/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150507748
27/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150745778
28/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150918209
29/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151201139
30/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151413118
31/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151617243
01/06/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151798964
02/06/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151985446
```

I need to add two columns:

First, the 1-day difference. In the above example, the `01/06/2017` row's new `1DayDifference` would be the `Value` minus the `02/06/2017` row's `Value`..

Second, the 7-day difference. The `02/06/2017` row's new `7DayDifference` would be the `Value` minus the `26/05/2017` row's `Value`.

```
TimeStamp            Device  Value      1DayDifference  7DayDifference
-------------------  ------  ---------  --------------  --------------
25/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150292432  215316  
26/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150507748  238030  
27/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150745778  172431  
28/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  150918209  282930  
29/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151201139  211979  
30/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151413118  204125  
31/05/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151617243  181721          1506532
01/06/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151798964  186482          1477698
02/06/2017 00:00:00  A_Mill  151985446
```

This is all nice and easy to achieve in Excel but I don't know where to start with it in T-SQL.

Comment: use row_number and from it self join each row with it next one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use lead as below

```
select *, [1DayDifference]= lead([value]) over(partition by Device order by [Timestamp]) - [Value] ,
    [7dayDifference] = lead([value]) over(partition by Device order by [Timestamp]) -
    lag([value], 6, null) over(partition by Device order by [Timestamp]) 
    from Yourdevice
```

Updated with correct logic for 7DayDifference

Output as below:

```
+-------------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
|        Timestamp        | Device |   value   | 1DayDifference | 7dayDifference |
+-------------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
| 2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 150292432 | 215316         | NULL           |
| 2017-05-26 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 150507748 | 238030         | NULL           |
| 2017-05-27 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 150745778 | 172431         | NULL           |
| 2017-05-28 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 150918209 | 282930         | NULL           |
| 2017-05-29 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 151201139 | 211979         | NULL           |
| 2017-05-30 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 151413118 | 204125         | NULL           |
| 2017-05-31 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 151617243 | 181721         | 1506532        |
| 2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 151798964 | 186482         | 1477698        |
| 2017-06-02 00:00:00.000 | A_Mill | 151985446 | NULL           | NULL           |
+-------------------------+--------+-----------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Same solution of me :)

Comment: Wow what a response, I have it working no, thank you all for you replies it has helpped me a great deal :)

Answer (score 1):

Use LAG for take previous values, for info [look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

try Something like this:

```
select [TimeStamp],  [Device],  [Value], 
       lag(value) over(order by [TimeStamp]) - [Value] as [1DayDifferance],
       lag(value, 6) over(order by [TimeStamp]) - [Value] as [7DayDifferance] 
from yourtable
```

Comment: You provided the french version linkof msdn  =) it's anice solution btw just be cautions it will work only from sql 2012+

Comment: lol yes its true, i change my link Thanks. As for the version of SQL Server this is precisely what is specified in the request. :)

Comment: Jean, if you're using anything less than 2012 you have other issues.

Comment: @Josh Nah, I'm using 2016 but there a lot of people out here using the strategy "if it's working don't touch it" so I'm not susprised to occasionally find SQL Server 2008--

Answer (score 0):

As I commented you can try to use row_number to create a column to identify each row and use the results in a self-join.

If you dont't like using #temp tables you can use a CTE with the same effect.

```
create table MyTable
(
    [TimeStamp] datetime not null
   ,[Device] varchar(100) not null
   ,[Value] int not null
)
GO

set dateformat dmy

insert into MyTable
values
 ('25/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',150292432)
,('26/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',150507748)
,('27/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',150745778)
,('28/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',150918209)
,('29/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',151201139)
,('30/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',151413118)
,('31/05/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',151617243)
,('01/06/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',151798964)
,('02/06/2017 00:00:00','A_Mill',151985446)
GO

select *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [TimeStamp] ASC) AS Row#
into #temp
from MyTable

select t0.*
, t1.Value - t0.Value as [1 day Difference]
, t2.Value - t0.Value as [7 day Difference]
from #temp t0
left join #temp t1 on t1.Row# = t0.Row# +1
left join #temp t2 on t2.Row# = t0.Row# +7
```

Results

```
2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  150292432   1   215316  1506532
2017-05-26 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  150507748   2   238030  1477698
2017-05-27 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  150745778   3   172431  NULL
2017-05-28 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  150918209   4   282930  NULL
2017-05-29 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  151201139   5   211979  NULL
2017-05-30 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  151413118   6   204125  NULL
2017-05-31 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  151617243   7   181721  NULL
2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  151798964   8   186482  NULL
2017-06-02 00:00:00.000 A_Mill  151985446   9   NULL    NULL
```